# using a typedef struct in more than one .h file

Tags: c, header, struct, typedef

I'm doing a huffman encoding algorithm in C and got in a problem here.

I have two different .h files that will use this struct:

```
typedef struct no{
  int qtd;
  char c;
  struct no* esq;
  struct no* dir;
}no;
```

So, my arv_huffman.h has that typedef and `typedef no** arvHuffman`

My other .h, heap.h, includes "arv_huffman.h" and uses `typedef no* heap`

Both files have no other implementations.  The message I get when I try to compile is:

```
arv_huffman.h:11: error: redefinition of ‘struct no’
arv_huffman.h:16: error: conflicting types for ‘no’
arv_huffman.h:16: note: previous declaration of ‘no’ was here
arv_huffman.h:18: error: conflicting types for ‘arvoreHuff’
arv_huffman.h:18: note: previous declaration of ‘arvoreHuff’ was here
```

**lines have the following code**

```
arv_huffman.h:11: "typedef struct no{"
arv_huffman.h:16: "}no;"
arv_huffman.h:18: "typedef no** arvoreHuff;"
```

What's going wrong and how do I fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to put [header guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your .h

Since the guards aren't present, it is seeing the same definition twice, and thinks you are redefining the struct.